# android layout problem

Tags: android, layout

I want the row to be scale automatically. The effect of my code is really strange...

i can't post images, so image is here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfkO.jpg

the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#FFFFF0"
```

>

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#CBCBCB"
/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/label"
    android:minHeight="60dip"
    android:maxHeight="120dip"
    android:layout_width="220dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:textColor="#0f93b8"

/>
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/people"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dip"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:textColor="#CBCBCB"

/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What firmware version are you using? I found this happens in 1.5 but not 1.6 or above!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be some confusion in what you are wanting to scale. To have the TextView scale automatically depending on the length of the content, you can set the height to non concrete values using wrap_content. This along with a minimum height will give you views that always display your content however they may not fit on one screen (you may have to put the overall view in a scrollview or a listview with the rows as elements).

If you want the Text itself to scale "automagically" ... well that's a little tougher as by default that behavior does not exist. You will have to measure the space left using the Canvas of the TextView and figure out the correct fontmetrics to use for the space available. I would extend TextView for this and override the various onMeasure() and draw() methods to determine the correct font needed. If your TextViews are of fixed size, it will simplify the task greatly.

Comment: I want the TextView scale automatically depending on the length of the content. You see that picture? I have set the android:layout_height to be "wrap_content" , and just now I removed the line "android:maxHeight="120dip". But it is still not work.

Comment: Ooooh I am sorry. I see. Hmmm, if you are putting them into a listview, try fill_parent on the linearlayout's height.